# Hola buena, tengo una duda acerca de enumerar filas en datagridview en c#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

```
private void verArticulos_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == numero.Index)
    {
        e.Value = e.RowIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es la pregunta?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como dijo gbianchi, no entendemos bien tu duda con ese fragmento de código, te recomiendo que leas los post que te pasó.

Por otro lado, en cuanto a enumerar filas de un grid view tengo un código que quizás pueda servirte...

```
    private void GrillaProveedores_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(GrillaProveedores.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString((e.RowIndex + 1).ToString(), e.InheritedRowStyle.Font, b, e.RowBounds.Location.X + 10, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + 4);
        }
    }
```

Simplemente tienes que crear un evento del datagrid view que se llama RowPostPaint
Te quedaría algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]